# Logging Level not changing on Simple Spock Test

Tags: java, spring, log4j, spock

I have a very simple Spring Boot 2.0 project with one Spock test.  The test uses the reactive WebClient (org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient) but nothing else Spring-related.  Everything is working well, but the logging is very noisy.  How can I turn it off?

The test is at `src/test/groovy/com/example`.  And I added these two files:

`src/main/resources/application.yml`:

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: ERROR
```

`src/main/resources/log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,stdout
```

(The noisy log statements are at DEBUG level)

I still get the noisy logs.  I even tried moving these files to `src/test/resources`.  How can I set the root log level in Spock??

Comment: try --echoErr while running test case

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that Spring Boot/Spock are using logback by default.  Adding this file fixed the issue:

`src/test/resources/logback.xml`:

```
<configuration />
```